# How can I center my different-sized images within a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to have a slideshow of my work but I'm new to html/css/jquery. I'm working with a jquery plugin that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slider').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 0, 
    next:   '#next', 
    prev:   '#prev' 
});
</script>
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<div align="center" id="slideshow">
        <div class="controller" id="prev"></div>
        <div id="slider">
        <img src="Images/Logo_01.jpg" width="960" height="576" alt="logo"/>
        <img src="Images/Logo_02.jpg" width="384" height="640" alt="logo"/>
        <img src="Images/Logo_03.jpg" width="640" height="640" alt="logo"/>
        <img src="Images/Logo_04.jpg" width="960" height="510" alt="logo"/>
        <img src="Images/Logo_05.jpg" width="956" height="640" alt="logo"/>
        </div>
        <div class="controller" id="next"></div>
</div>
```

I've been modifying the slider id & I've tried everything I know-margin:0 auto;, text-align: center, display: block; but nothing's working. help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Using `jQuery`

```
$('#slider img').css({position: 'relative', margin: 'auto'});
```

Using `CSS`, you have to use `!important` as `cycle jQuery plugin` is adding `inline CSS` to images

```
#slider img {
    position: relative !important;
    margin: auto !important;
}
```